# Display Activity Indicator on property change in mvvmcross

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to show loading screen when a network request is made. I have a LoginViewModel where I have defined a property IsLoading. Now when it changes I want to display activity indicator. I am trying to use BTProgressHUD here. Although I have been able to bind my controls with the ViewModel but I am not able to bind BTProgressHUD as show or hide. Following is how I am binding other controls:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
        set.Bind(txtUser).To(vm => vm.Username);
        set.Bind(txtPassword).To(vm => vm.Password);
        set.Bind(btnLogin).To(vm => vm.LoginCommand);
        set.Apply();
```

i have tried following for BTProgressHUD but it doesn't work:

```
set.Bind(BTProgressHUD.Show()).To(vm => vm.IsLoading);
```

I am not able to compile as I am getting error for Bind function. Is it possible to create a closure(like in iOS) bound with a property in ViewModel and for any change in property can do some operation in View?

Answer (score 0):

I presume your LoginCommand calls a login function. In that function you should call `BTProgressHUD.Show()`, followed by your login process.

You should wrap your login process in a `try`/`catch` and in the `finally` you should call `BTProgressHUD.Dismiss()`.

This has the added benefit of not having to repeat the code in all of your platforms.

As an extra, you could create a `BaseViewModel` which your view models inherit from, give it an `IsLoading` property, and set your `BTProgressHUD.Show()` and `BTProgressHUD.Dismiss()` whenever it is called.

```
private bool _isLoading = false;
public virtual bool IsLoading
{
    get { return _isLoading; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _isLoading, value);
        if (value)
            BTProgressHUD.Show();
        else BTProgressHUD.Dismiss();
    }
}
```